# What's the different about this two code style

Tags: angular, service, angular-httpclient

It's about calling API using service in angular 7.

Async Http Style :

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
.
.
public variable: BehaviorSubject<any>  = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)
.
.
public async getSomeThing() {
 try {
   this.http.get('api url')
   .pipe().subscribe((res: any) => {

        this.variable.next(res.data)

        return resolve(this.variable)          

   })
 }
 catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
 }
}
```

Normal Http Style :

```
public getSomeThing() {
  return this.http.get('api url')
}
```

I received this angular project from someone else. I don't understand why he use async for calling api. Is it for a better performance?

Comment: There is not really specific about performance.

Comment: for know, Angular Performance Checklist, refer to this link: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist

Comment: The main difference is how you consume these APIs.